# Undefined control sequence when using \begin{equation}

Tags: equations, errors

I have loaded amsmath and then giving the equation

```
\begin{equation}
RMSE = \sum \limit_{i=1}^{d} \left (\frac{original(i)-predicted(i)}{original(i)} \right) ^ 2
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
```

It gives undefined control sequence error, please help.

Comment: `\limit` is undefined you meant `\limits`  but you can simply delete it as `\limits` does nothing there, `\sum` uses limits anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question, error is resolved now.

Comment: The error (which you didn't post for us to see) has a line break after `\limit`.  That's how you know that `\limit` is the problem.  But you should do something with `RMSE` and `original`, so that TeX doesn't think you're multiplying 4 or 8 variables.

Comment: Incidentally, that's not the [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMSE) ….

Answer (score 5):

A quick fix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{RMSE} = \sum_{i=1}^{d}
  \left(\frac{\mathrm{original}(i)-\mathrm{predicted}(i)}{\mathrm{original}(i)}
  \right)^2
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm`.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the reminder!! It's corrected.